# How to modify .htaccess for web app (in combination with WordPress 3.0.1)

Tags: apache, wordpress, .htaccess, apache2

My question is about .htaccess

I am using WordPress 3.0.1 as the front end of my web application.
I want most HTTP accesses to follow the normal WordPress flow.

However, I have created a special "Page" in WordPress that has embedded PHP code that powers my web app.

URL's of this form "http://site.com/app/" already go to the correct page.

URL's of this form "http://site.com/app/?a=alpha&b=beta" go to the same page, and pass parameters to my web app.  This is correct, but the URL looks ugly.

Here is my question:

I want nice looking URLs of this format:

```
http://site.com/app/alpha/beta
```

to be rewritten this way ->

```
http://site.com/app/?a=alpha&b=beta
```

I have tried adding various things in .htaccess, but I can't get it to work.  I typically end up with a WordPress 404 page being displayed.

Here is the .htaccess file that was created when installing WordPress 3.0.1

```
# .htaccess
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I am sure there must be lots of folks using WordPress as a front end for their web app, and others with expertise in .htaccess syntax.  Any answers or pointers to solutions would be appreciated.

thanks in advance,

David Jones

dxjones@gmail.com

http://dxjones.com

Answer (score 0):

David, don't know the answer for sure, but here's a thought.

You can use plugins like this: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/exec-php/

It let's you execute code from within pages or posts.

If you look into the WP documentation, you could easily tie another PHP app into WP.

Comment: This does not answer my question. ... I am already using the Exec-PHP plugin to execute PHP code on my WordPress "Page" called "app".  This is working.  My question is about using .htaccess to rewrite HTTP requests so that this URL1 = "http://site.com/app/alpha/beta/" gets rewritten to URL2 = "http://site.com/app/?a=alpha&b=beta".  If I type in that URL2 directly, everything works.  I want to know how to make URL1 work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, to use rewrite rules in .htaccess, two things are required:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
```

Then this rule will do what you describe:

```
RewriteRule ^app/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /app/?a=$1&b=$2 [L]
```

- FYI ... `[^/]` matches any character except for "/"
- and the `[L]` at the end will make this rewrite invisible to the user --- it's only passed to your application.

#### *UPDATE*

To make visitors using old links automatically redirect to the nicer URL (and possibly improve search engine mapping of webapp pages), add an additional rule --- like this one:

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} a=([^&]+)&b=([^&]+)
 RewriteRule ^app/?$ /app/%1/%2  [R=301]
```

The rule above turns the a and b parameters into your nice URL -- however, it would not pass on additional query parameters.  (i.e. site.com/app?a=me&b=you&tag=zebra would redirect, but 'tag' parameter would be discarded in the process.)  Here is a variation that allows for additional parameters:

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|.*&)a=([^&]+)&b=([^&]+)(&.*|$)
 RewriteRule ^app/?$ /app/%2/%3?%1%4  [R=302]
```